# geom_abline multiple slopes and intercepts

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Considering this initial data frame (yld_sum):

```
  coef     pred      se    ci.lb    ci.ub    cr.lb    cr.ub Yld_class
   b0 3164.226 114.256 2940.289 3388.164 2142.724 4185.728      1Low
   b1  -20.698   3.511  -27.580  -13.816  -50.520    9.124      1Low
   b0 3985.287 133.220 3724.180 4246.394 2954.998 5015.576      2Low
   b1  -14.371   4.185  -22.573   -6.168  -44.525   15.784      2Low
```

How can I simplify my syntax to plot the two estimated regression lines with their respective CI, and obtain the following plot?

[image]

This is my verbose code:

```
library(tidyverse)

yld_sum_est <- yld_sum %>% select(Yld_class, coef, pred) %>% 
  spread(coef, pred)  

yld_sum_low <- yld_sum %>% select(Yld_class, coef, ci.lb) %>% 
  spread(coef, ci.lb)

yld_sum_up <- yld_sum %>% select(Yld_class, coef, ci.ub) %>% 
  spread(coef, ci.ub)

ggplot() + 
  geom_abline(data = yld_sum_est, aes(intercept = b0, slope = b1)) +
  geom_abline(data = yld_sum_low, aes(intercept = b0, slope = b1), linetype= "dashed") +
  geom_abline(data = yld_sum_up, aes(intercept = b0, slope = b1), linetype= "dashed") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,60), name="x") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(1000, 4200), name="y")
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your dissatisfaction? Are you unhappy with the data transformation code? The plotting code? The generality and scalability?

Comment: I would like to use the initial table to do that plot... I'd like to avoid the intermediate data frames...

Comment: Well, you can't very well plot directly from that table. The simplification I would suggest would be combining your data frames into one with a single column indicating estimate, ub, or lb, and then you could do a single `geom_abline` with `linetype = ifelse(type == "estimate"), group = interaction(type, Yld_class)` aesthetics. I don't see how your transformation code can get much simpler with that table as the start, but maybe starting from the models would be easier...

Comment: I will update the OP Gregor addressing your comment..

Comment: @Gregor I create a new question addressing your comment, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700172/extract-coefficients-from-linear-mixed-model-estimates-and-95ci-for-plotting-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a 'data shape' problem. If you want `ggplot` to draw multiple objects within a single call, the object parameters (like `intercept` and `slope`) need to be the columns of your data frame and the object instances to be the rows by the time the data enters `ggplot`.

Particularly in your case you need a data frame with 6 rows - one for each line, each holding the identity of the line and it's parameters, like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

# data block from the question is in clipboard
read.table("clipboard", header = T) -> yld_sum

yld_sum %>%
  select(-starts_with("cr"), -se) %>%
  gather(metric, value, -coef, -Yld_class) %>%
  spread(coef, value) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_abline(aes(
    intercept = b0, 
    slope = b1,
    linetype = if_else(metric == "pred", "", "dashed")),
    ) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,60), name="x") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(1000, 4200), name="y") +
  guides(linetype = F)
```

Feel free to explore the data reshaping process by putting RStudio's `View` call after successive steps (like `%>% View`).

The final shape of the data, for illustration (after the `spread()` call):

```
  Yld_class metric       b0      b1
1      1Low  ci.lb 2940.289 -27.580
2      1Low  ci.ub 3388.164 -13.816
3      1Low   pred 3164.226 -20.698
4      2Low  ci.lb 3724.180 -22.573
5      2Low  ci.ub 4246.394  -6.168
6      2Low   pred 3985.287 -14.371
```