# ggplot2 Equation of a line and r^2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have seen another post for an equation for a log10 graph using ggplot in R. I can not seem to get it to work. Here is my [df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys2br.png) I used dput(a) and placed the info on the bottom of the question.

Here is the one I am trying to use as an example but I keep getting errors.
[Add regression line equation and R^2 on graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/add-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph)

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

p2 <- ggplot(a, aes(x = Discharge, y = Gageheight) ) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                 labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +

  theme_bw() 
p2

print(p2 + ggtitle("USGS 11381500 MILL C NR LOS MOLINOS CA","Stage-Discharge Rating"))
```

It creates this graph:

[image: log Graph]

```r
a <- structure(list(Gageheight = c(1, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 
1.06, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09, 1.1, 1.11, 1.12, 1.13, 1.14, 1.15, 1.16, 
1.17, 1.18, 1.19, 1.2, 1.21, 1.22, 1.23, 1.24, 1.25, 1.26, 1.27, 
1.28, 1.29, 1.3, 1.31, 1.32, 1.33, 1.34, 1.35, 1.36, 1.37, 1.38, 
1.39, 1.4, 1.41, 1.42, 1.43, 1.44, 1.45, 1.46, 1.47, 1.48, 1.49, 
1.5, 1.51, 1.52, 1.53, 1.54, 1.55, 1.56, 1.57, 1.58, 1.59, 1.6, 
1.61, 1.62, 1.63, 1.64, 1.65, 1.66, 1.67, 1.68, 1.69, 1.7, 1.71, 
1.72, 1.73, 1.74, 1.75, 1.76, 1.77, 1.78, 1.79, 1.8, 1.81, 1.82, 
1.83, 1.84, 1.85, 1.86, 1.87, 1.88, 1.89, 1.9, 1.91, 1.92, 1.93, 
1.94, 1.95, 1.96, 1.97, 1.98, 1.99, 2, 2.01, 2.02, 2.03, 2.04, 
2.05, 2.06, 2.07, 2.08, 2.09, 2.1, 2.11, 2.12, 2.13, 2.14, 2.15, 
2.16, 2.17, 2.18, 2.19, 2.2, 2.21, 2.22, 2.23, 2.24, 2.26, 2.27, 
2.28, 2.29, 2.3, 2.31, 2.32, 2.33, 2.35, 2.36, 2.37, 2.38, 2.39, 
2.4, 2.41, 2.42, 2.44, 2.45, 2.46, 2.47, 2.48, 2.49, 2.5, 2.51, 
2.52, 2.54, 2.55, 2.56, 2.57, 2.58, 2.59, 2.6, 2.61, 2.63, 2.64, 
2.65, 2.66, 2.67, 2.68, 2.69, 2.7, 2.71, 2.73, 2.74, 2.75, 2.76, 
2.77, 2.78, 2.79, 2.8, 2.82, 2.83, 2.84, 2.85, 2.86, 2.87, 2.88, 
2.89, 2.91, 2.92, 2.93, 2.94, 2.95, 2.96, 2.97, 2.98, 2.99, 3, 
3.01, 3.02, 3.03, 3.04, 3.05, 3.06, 3.07, 3.08, 3.09, 3.1, 3.11, 
3.12, 3.13, 3.14, 3.15, 3.16, 3.17, 3.18, 3.19, 3.2, 3.21, 3.22, 
3.23, 3.24, 3.25, 3.26, 3.27, 3.28, 3.29, 3.3, 3.31, 3.32, 3.33, 
3.34, 3.35, 3.36, 3.37, 3.38, 3.39, 3.4, 3.41, 3.42, 3.43, 3.44, 
3.45, 3.46, 3.47, 3.48, 3.49, 3.5, 3.51, 3.52, 3.53, 3.54, 3.55, 
3.56, 3.57, 3.58, 3.59, 3.6, 3.61, 3.62, 3.63, 3.64, 3.65, 3.66, 
3.67, 3.68, 3.69, 3.7, 3.71, 3.72, 3.73, 3.74, 3.75, 3.76, 3.77, 
3.78, 3.79, 3.8, 3.81, 3.82, 3.83, 3.84, 3.85, 3.86, 3.87, 3.88, 
3.89, 3.9, 3.91, 3.92, 3.93, 3.94, 3.95, 3.96, 3.97, 3.98, 3.99, 
4, 4.01, 4.02, 4.03, 4.04, 4.05, 4.06, 4.07, 4.08, 4.09, 4.1, 
4.11, 4.12, 4.13, 4.14, 4.15, 4.16, 4.17, 4.18, 4.19, 4.2, 4.21, 
4.22, 4.23, 4.24, 4.25, 4.26, 4.27, 4.28, 4.29, 4.3, 4.31, 4.32, 
4.33, 4.34, 4.35, 4.36, 4.37, 4.38, 4.39, 4.4, 4.41, 4.42, 4.43, 
4.44, 4.45, 4.46, 4.47, 4.48, 4.49, 4.5, 4.51, 4.52, 4.53, 4.54, 
4.55, 4.56, 4.57, 4.58, 4.59, 4.6, 4.61, 4.62, 4.63, 4.64, 4.65, 
4.66, 4.67, 4.68, 4.69, 4.7, 4.71, 4.72, 4.73, 4.74, 4.75, 4.76, 
4.77, 4.78, 4.79, 4.8, 4.81, 4.82, 4.83, 4.84, 4.85, 4.86, 4.87, 
4.88, 4.89, 4.9, 4.91, 4.92, 4.93, 4.94, 4.95, 4.96, 4.97, 4.98, 
4.99, 5, 5.01, 5.02, 5.03, 5.04, 5.05, 5.06, 5.07, 5.08, 5.09, 
5.1, 5.11, 5.12, 5.13, 5.14, 5.15, 5.16, 5.17, 5.18, 5.19, 5.2, 
5.21, 5.22, 5.23, 5.24, 5.25, 5.26, 5.27, 5.28, 5.29, 5.3, 5.31, 
5.32, 5.33, 5.34, 5.35, 5.36, 5.37, 5.38, 5.39, 5.4, 5.41, 5.42, 
5.43, 5.44, 5.45, 5.46, 5.47, 5.48, 5.49, 5.5, 5.51, 5.52, 5.53, 
5.54, 5.55, 5.56, 5.57, 5.58, 5.59, 5.6, 5.61, 5.62, 5.63, 5.64, 
5.65, 5.66, 5.67, 5.68, 5.69, 5.7, 5.71, 5.72, 5.73, 5.74, 5.75, 
5.76, 5.77, 5.78, 5.79, 5.8, 5.81, 5.82, 5.83, 5.84, 5.85, 5.86, 
5.87, 5.88, 5.89, 5.9, 5.91, 5.92, 5.93, 5.94, 5.95, 5.96, 5.97, 
5.98, 5.99, 6, 6.01, 6.02, 6.03, 6.04, 6.05, 6.06, 6.07, 6.08, 
6.09, 6.1, 6.11, 6.12, 6.13, 6.14, 6.15, 6.16, 6.17, 6.18, 6.19, 
6.2, 6.21, 6.22, 6.23, 6.24, 6.25, 6.26, 6.27, 6.28, 6.29, 6.3, 
6.31, 6.32, 6.33, 6.34, 6.35, 6.36, 6.37, 6.38, 6.39, 6.4, 6.41, 
6.42, 6.43, 6.44, 6.45, 6.46, 6.47, 6.48, 6.49, 6.5, 6.51, 6.52, 
6.53, 6.54, 6.55, 6.56, 6.57, 6.58, 6.59, 6.6, 6.61, 6.62, 6.63, 
6.64, 6.65, 6.66, 6.67, 6.68, 6.69, 6.7, 6.71, 6.72, 6.73, 6.74, 
6.75, 6.76, 6.77, 6.78, 6.79, 6.8, 6.81, 6.82, 6.83, 6.84, 6.85, 
6.86, 6.87, 6.88, 6.89, 6.9, 6.91, 6.92, 6.93, 6.94, 6.95, 6.96, 
6.97, 6.98, 6.99, 7, 7.01, 7.02, 7.03, 7.04, 7.05, 7.06, 7.07, 
7.08, 7.09, 7.1, 7.11, 7.12, 7.13, 7.14, 7.15, 7.16, 7.17, 7.18, 
7.19, 7.2, 7.21, 7.22, 7.23, 7.24, 7.25, 7.26, 7.27, 7.28, 7.29, 
7.3, 7.31, 7.32, 7.33, 7.34, 7.35, 7.36, 7.37, 7.38, 7.39, 7.4, 
7.41, 7.42, 7.43, 7.44, 7.45, 7.46, 7.47, 7.48, 7.49, 7.5, 7.51, 
7.52, 7.53, 7.54, 7.55, 7.56, 7.57, 7.58, 7.59, 7.6, 7.61, 7.62, 
7.63, 7.64, 7.65, 7.66, 7.67, 7.68, 7.69, 7.7, 7.71, 7.72, 7.73, 
7.74, 7.75, 7.76, 7.77, 7.78, 7.79, 7.8, 7.81, 7.82, 7.83, 7.84, 
7.85, 7.86, 7.87, 7.88, 7.89, 7.9, 7.91, 7.92, 7.93, 7.94, 7.95, 
7.96, 7.97, 7.98, 7.99, 8, 8.01, 8.02, 8.03, 8.04, 8.05, 8.06, 
8.07, 8.08, 8.09, 8.1, 8.11, 8.12, 8.13, 8.14, 8.15, 8.16, 8.17, 
8.18, 8.19, 8.2, 8.21, 8.22, 8.23, 8.24, 8.25, 8.26, 8.27, 8.28, 
8.29, 8.3, 8.31, 8.32, 8.33, 8.34, 8.35, 8.36, 8.37, 8.38, 8.39, 
8.4, 8.41, 8.42, 8.43, 8.44, 8.45, 8.46, 8.47, 8.48, 8.49, 8.5, 
8.51, 8.52, 8.53, 8.54, 8.55, 8.56, 8.57, 8.58, 8.59, 8.6, 8.61, 
8.62, 8.63, 8.64, 8.65, 8.66, 8.67, 8.68, 8.69, 8.7, 8.71, 8.72, 
8.73, 8.74, 8.75, 8.76, 8.77, 8.78, 8.79, 8.8, 8.81, 8.82, 8.83, 
8.84, 8.85, 8.86, 8.87, 8.88, 8.89, 8.9, 8.91, 8.92, 8.93, 8.94, 
8.95, 8.96, 8.97, 8.98, 8.99, 9, 9.01, 9.02, 9.03, 9.04, 9.05, 
9.06, 9.07, 9.08, 9.09, 9.1, 9.11, 9.12, 9.13, 9.14, 9.15, 9.16, 
9.17, 9.18, 9.19, 9.2, 9.21, 9.22, 9.23, 9.24, 9.25, 9.26, 9.27, 
9.28, 9.29, 9.3, 9.31, 9.32, 9.33, 9.34, 9.35, 9.36, 9.37, 9.38, 
9.39, 9.4, 9.41, 9.42, 9.43, 9.44, 9.45, 9.46, 9.47, 9.48, 9.49, 
9.5, 9.51, 9.52, 9.53, 9.54, 9.55, 9.56, 9.57, 9.58, 9.59, 9.6, 
9.61, 9.62, 9.63, 9.64, 9.65, 9.66, 9.67, 9.68, 9.69, 9.7, 9.71, 
9.72, 9.73, 9.74, 9.75, 9.76, 9.77, 9.78, 9.79, 9.8, 9.81, 9.82, 
9.83, 9.84, 9.85, 9.86, 9.87, 9.88, 9.89, 9.9, 9.91, 9.92, 9.93, 
9.94, 9.95, 9.96, 9.97, 9.98, 9.99, 10, 10.01, 10.02, 10.03, 
10.04, 10.05, 10.06, 10.07, 10.08, 10.09, 10.1, 10.11, 10.12, 
10.13, 10.14, 10.15, 10.16, 10.17, 10.18, 10.19, 10.2, 10.21, 
10.22, 10.23, 10.24, 10.25, 10.26, 10.27, 10.28, 10.29, 10.3, 
10.31, 10.32, 10.33, 10.34, 10.35, 10.36, 10.37, 10.38, 10.39, 
10.4, 10.41, 10.42, 10.43, 10.44, 10.45, 10.46, 10.47, 10.48, 
10.49, 10.5, 10.51, 10.52, 10.53, 10.54, 10.55, 10.56, 10.57, 
10.58, 10.59, 10.6, 10.61, 10.62, 10.63, 10.64, 10.65, 10.66, 
10.67, 10.68, 10.69, 10.7, 10.71, 10.72, 10.73, 10.74, 10.75, 
10.76, 10.77, 10.78, 10.79, 10.8, 10.81, 10.82, 10.83, 10.84, 
10.85, 10.86, 10.87, 10.88, 10.89, 10.9, 10.91, 10.92, 10.93, 
10.94, 10.95, 10.96, 10.97, 10.98, 10.99, 11, 11.01, 11.02, 11.03, 
11.04, 11.05, 11.06, 11.07, 11.08, 11.09, 11.1, 11.11, 11.12, 
11.13, 11.14, 11.15, 11.16, 11.17, 11.18, 11.19, 11.2, 11.21, 
11.22, 11.23, 11.24, 11.25, 11.26, 11.27, 11.28, 11.29, 11.3, 
11.31, 11.32, 11.33, 11.34, 11.35, 11.36, 11.37, 11.38, 11.39, 
11.4, 11.41, 11.42, 11.43, 11.44, 11.45, 11.46, 11.47, 11.48, 
11.49, 11.5, 11.51, 11.52, 11.53, 11.54, 11.55, 11.56, 11.57, 
11.58, 11.59, 11.6, 11.61, 11.62, 11.63, 11.64, 11.65, 11.66, 
11.67, 11.68, 11.69, 11.7, 11.71, 11.72, 11.73, 11.74, 11.75, 
11.76, 11.77, 11.78, 11.79, 11.8, 11.81, 11.82, 11.83, 11.84, 
11.85, 11.86, 11.87, 11.88, 11.89, 11.9, 11.91, 11.92, 11.93, 
11.94, 11.95, 11.96, 11.97, 11.98, 11.99, 12, 12.01, 12.02, 12.03, 
12.04, 12.05, 12.06, 12.07, 12.08, 12.09, 12.1, 12.11, 12.12, 
12.13, 12.14, 12.15, 12.16, 12.17, 12.18, 12.19, 12.2, 12.21, 
12.22, 12.23, 12.24, 12.25, 12.26, 12.27, 12.28, 12.29, 12.3, 
12.31, 12.32, 12.33, 12.34, 12.35, 12.36, 12.37, 12.38, 12.39, 
12.4, 12.41, 12.42, 12.43, 12.44, 12.45, 12.46, 12.47, 12.48, 
12.49, 12.5, 12.51, 12.52, 12.53, 12.54, 12.55, 12.56, 12.57, 
12.58, 12.59, 12.6, 12.61, 12.62, 12.63, 12.64, 12.65, 12.66, 
12.67, 12.68, 12.69, 12.7, 12.71, 12.72, 12.73, 12.74, 12.75, 
12.76, 12.77, 12.78, 12.79, 12.8, 12.81, 12.82, 12.83, 12.84, 
12.85, 12.86, 12.87, 12.88, 12.89, 12.9, 12.91, 12.92, 12.93, 
12.94, 12.95, 12.96, 12.97, 12.98, 12.99, 13, 13.01, 13.02, 13.03, 
13.04, 13.05, 13.06, 13.07, 13.08, 13.09, 13.1, 13.11, 13.12, 
13.13, 13.14, 13.15, 13.16, 13.17, 13.18, 13.19, 13.2, 13.21, 
13.22, 13.23, 13.24, 13.25, 13.26, 13.27, 13.28, 13.29, 13.3, 
13.31, 13.32, 13.33, 13.34, 13.35, 13.36, 13.37, 13.38, 13.39, 
13.4, 13.41, 13.42, 13.43, 13.44, 13.45, 13.46, 13.47, 13.48, 
13.49, 13.5, 13.51, 13.52, 13.53, 13.54, 13.55, 13.56, 13.57, 
13.58, 13.59, 13.6, 13.61, 13.62, 13.63, 13.64, 13.65, 13.66, 
13.67, 13.68, 13.69, 13.7, 13.71, 13.72, 13.73, 13.74, 13.75, 
13.76, 13.77, 13.78, 13.79, 13.8, 13.81, 13.82, 13.83, 13.84, 
13.85, 13.86, 13.87, 13.88, 13.89, 13.9, 13.91, 13.92, 13.93, 
13.94, 13.95, 13.96, 13.97, 13.98, 13.99, 14, 14.01, 14.02, 14.03, 
14.04, 14.05, 14.06, 14.07, 14.08, 14.09, 14.1, 14.11, 14.12, 
14.13, 14.14, 14.15, 14.16, 14.17, 14.18, 14.19, 14.2, 14.21, 
14.22, 14.23, 14.24, 14.25, 14.26, 14.27, 14.28, 14.29, 14.3, 
14.31, 14.32, 14.33, 14.34, 14.35, 14.36, 14.37, 14.38, 14.39, 
14.4, 14.41, 14.42, 14.43, 14.44, 14.45, 14.46, 14.47, 14.48, 
14.49, 14.5, 14.51, 14.52, 14.53, 14.54, 14.55, 14.56, 14.57, 
14.58, 14.59, 14.6, 14.61, 14.62, 14.63, 14.64, 14.65, 14.66, 
14.67, 14.68, 14.69, 14.7, 14.71, 14.72, 14.73, 14.74, 14.75, 
14.76, 14.77, 14.78, 14.79, 14.8, 14.81, 14.82, 14.83, 14.84, 
14.85, 14.86, 14.87, 14.88, 14.89, 14.9, 14.91, 14.92, 14.93, 
14.94, 14.95, 14.96, 14.97, 14.98, 14.99, 15, 15.01, 15.02, 15.03, 
15.04, 15.05, 15.06, 15.07, 15.08, 15.09, 15.1, 15.11, 15.12, 
15.13, 15.14, 15.15, 15.16, 15.17, 15.18, 15.19, 15.2, 15.21, 
15.22, 15.23, 15.24, 15.25, 15.26, 15.27, 15.28, 15.29, 15.3, 
15.31, 15.32, 15.33, 15.34, 15.35, 15.36, 15.37, 15.38, 15.39, 
15.4, 15.41, 15.42, 15.43, 15.44, 15.45, 15.46, 15.47, 15.48, 
15.49, 15.5, 15.51, 15.52, 15.53, 15.54, 15.55, 15.56, 15.57, 
15.58, 15.59, 15.6, 15.61, 15.62, 15.63, 15.64, 15.65, 15.66, 
15.67, 15.68, 15.69, 15.7, 15.71, 15.72, 15.73, 15.74, 15.75, 
15.76, 15.77, 15.78, 15.79, 15.8, 15.81, 15.82, 15.83, 15.84, 
15.85, 15.86, 15.87, 15.88, 15.89, 15.9, 15.91, 15.92, 15.93, 
15.94, 15.95, 15.96, 15.97, 15.98, 15.99, 16, 16.01, 16.02, 16.03, 
16.04, 16.05, 16.06, 16.07, 16.08, 16.09, 16.1, 16.11, 16.12, 
16.13, 16.14, 16.15, 16.16, 16.17, 16.18, 16.19, 16.2, 16.21, 
16.22, 16.23, 16.24, 16.25, 16.26, 16.27, 16.28, 16.29, 16.3, 
16.31, 16.32, 16.33, 16.34, 16.35, 16.36, 16.37, 16.38, 16.39, 
16.4, 16.41, 16.42, 16.43, 16.44, 16.45, 16.46, 16.47, 16.48, 
16.49, 16.5, 16.51, 16.52, 16.53, 16.54, 16.55, 16.56, 16.57, 
16.58, 16.59, 16.6, 16.61, 16.62, 16.63, 16.64, 16.65, 16.66, 
16.67, 16.68, 16.69, 16.7, 16.71, 16.72, 16.73, 16.74, 16.75, 
16.76, 16.77, 16.78, 16.79, 16.8, 16.81, 16.82, 16.83, 16.84, 
16.85, 16.86, 16.87, 16.88, 16.89, 16.9, 16.91, 16.92, 16.93, 
16.94, 16.95, 16.96, 16.97, 16.98, 16.99, 17, 17.01, 17.02, 17.03, 
17.04, 17.05, 17.06, 17.07, 17.08, 17.09, 17.1, 17.11, 17.12, 
17.13, 17.14, 17.15, 17.16, 17.17, 17.18, 17.19, 17.2, 17.21, 
17.22, 17.23, 17.24, 17.25, 17.26, 17.27, 17.28, 17.29, 17.3, 
17.31, 17.32, 17.33, 17.34, 17.35, 17.36, 17.37, 17.38, 17.39, 
17.4, 17.41, 17.42, 17.43, 17.44, 17.45, 17.46, 17.47, 17.48, 
17.49, 17.5, 17.51, 17.52, 17.53, 17.54, 17.55, 17.56, 17.57, 
17.58), Discharge = c(9.92, 10.48, 11.05, 11.64, 12.24, 12.86, 
13.49, 14.13, 14.79, 15.47, 16.16, 16.86, 17.58, 18.32, 19.06, 
19.83, 20.6, 21.4, 22.2, 23.02, 23.86, 24.71, 25.57, 26.45, 27.34, 
28.25, 29.17, 30.1, 31.05, 32.02, 33, 33.99, 35, 36.02, 37.05, 
38.1, 39.17, 40.25, 41.34, 42.44, 43.56, 44.7, 45.85, 47.01, 
48.19, 49.38, 50.59, 51.81, 53.04, 54.29, 55.55, 56.82, 58.11, 
59.42, 60.74, 62.07, 63.41, 64.77, 66.15, 67.54, 68.94, 70.35, 
71.78, 73.23, 74.68, 76.16, 77.64, 79.14, 80.65, 82.18, 83.72, 
85.28, 86.85, 88.43, 90.03, 91.64, 93.26, 94.9, 96.55, 98.22, 
99.9, 101.59, 103.3, 105.02, 106.75, 108.5, 110.26, 112.04, 113.83, 
115.63, 117.45, 119.28, 121.13, 122.99, 124.86, 126.74, 128.64, 
130.56, 132.48, 134.42, 136.38, 138.35, 140.33, 142.32, 144.33, 
146.36, 148.39, 150.44, 152.51, 154.58, 156.68, 158.78, 160.9, 
163.03, 165.18, 167.33, 169.51, 171.69, 173.89, 176.11, 178.33, 
180.84, 183.37, 185.91, 188.47, 191.05, 193.64, 196.25, 198.88, 
201.53, 204.19, 206.87, 209.56, 212.27, 215, 217.75, 220.51, 
223.29, 226.09, 228.9, 231.73, 234.58, 237.45, 240.33, 243.23, 
246.14, 249.07, 252.02, 254.99, 257.97, 260.97, 263.98, 267.02, 
270.07, 273.13, 276.22, 279.32, 282.43, 285.57, 288.72, 291.88, 
295.07, 298.27, 301.48, 304.72, 307.97, 311.24, 314.52, 317.82, 
321.14, 324.47, 327.82, 331.19, 334.58, 337.98, 341.4, 344.83, 
348.28, 351.75, 355.23, 358.73, 362.25, 365.79, 369.34, 372.9, 
376.49, 380.09, 383.71, 386.95, 390.21, 393.48, 396.77, 400.07, 
403.38, 406.7, 410.04, 413.39, 416.76, 420.14, 423.53, 426.93, 
430.35, 433.78, 437.22, 440.68, 444.15, 447.64, 451.13, 454.64, 
458.17, 461.7, 465.25, 468.82, 472.39, 475.98, 479.58, 483.2, 
486.83, 490.47, 494.12, 497.79, 501.47, 505.17, 508.88, 512.6, 
516.33, 520.08, 523.84, 527.61, 531.4, 535.2, 539.01, 542.84, 
546.68, 550.53, 554.39, 558.27, 562.16, 566.07, 569.98, 573.92, 
577.86, 581.82, 585.79, 589.77, 593.77, 597.77, 601.8, 605.83, 
609.88, 613.94, 618.02, 622.11, 626.21, 630.32, 634.45, 638.59, 
642.74, 646.91, 651.09, 655.28, 659.48, 663.7, 667.93, 672.18, 
676.43, 680.7, 684.99, 689.28, 693.59, 697.92, 702.25, 706.6, 
710.96, 715.34, 719.73, 724.13, 728.54, 732.97, 737.41, 741.86, 
746.32, 750.8, 755.29, 759.8, 764.32, 768.85, 773.39, 777.95, 
782.52, 787.1, 791.97, 796.86, 801.77, 806.69, 811.62, 816.57, 
821.54, 826.52, 831.52, 836.53, 841.56, 846.6, 851.66, 856.74, 
861.83, 866.93, 872.05, 877.19, 882.34, 887.51, 892.69, 897.89, 
903.11, 908.34, 913.58, 918.84, 924.12, 929.41, 934.72, 940.04, 
945.38, 950.74, 956.1, 961.49, 966.89, 972.31, 977.74, 983.19, 
988.65, 994.13, 999.62, 1005.13, 1010.66, 1016.2, 1021.76, 1027.33, 
1032.92, 1038.52, 1044.14, 1049.77, 1055.42, 1061.09, 1066.77, 
1072.47, 1078.18, 1083.91, 1089.65, 1095.41, 1101.18, 1106.97, 
1112.78, 1118.6, 1124.44, 1130.29, 1136.16, 1142.05, 1147.95, 
1153.86, 1159.79, 1165.74, 1171.7, 1177.68, 1183.67, 1189.68, 
1195.71, 1201.75, 1207.8, 1213.88, 1219.96, 1226.07, 1232.19, 
1238.32, 1244.47, 1250.64, 1256.82, 1263.02, 1269.23, 1275.46, 
1281.7, 1287.96, 1294.24, 1300.53, 1306.84, 1313.16, 1319.5, 
1325.85, 1332.22, 1338.61, 1345.01, 1351.43, 1357.86, 1364.31, 
1370.77, 1377.25, 1383.75, 1390.26, 1396.78, 1403.33, 1409.89, 
1416.46, 1423.05, 1429.66, 1436.28, 1442.91, 1449.57, 1456.23, 
1462.92, 1469.62, 1476.33, 1483.07, 1489.81, 1496.58, 1503.36, 
1510.15, 1516.96, 1523.79, 1530.63, 1537.49, 1544.36, 1551.25, 
1558.15, 1565.07, 1572.01, 1578.96, 1585.93, 1592.91, 1599.91, 
1606.93, 1613.96, 1621.01, 1628.07, 1635.15, 1642.24, 1649.35, 
1656.48, 1663.62, 1670.78, 1677.95, 1685.14, 1692.34, 1699.56, 
1706.8, 1714.05, 1721.32, 1728.6, 1735.9, 1743.22, 1750.55, 1757.9, 
1765.26, 1772.64, 1780.03, 1787.44, 1794.87, 1802.31, 1809.77, 
1817.24, 1824.73, 1832.24, 1839.76, 1847.3, 1854.85, 1862.42, 
1870, 1877.61, 1885.22, 1892.85, 1900.5, 1908.17, 1915.85, 1923.54, 
1931.25, 1938.98, 1946.72, 1954.48, 1962.26, 1970.05, 1977.86, 
1985.68, 1993.52, 2001.37, 2009.24, 2017.13, 2025.03, 2032.95, 
2040.88, 2048.83, 2056.8, 2064.78, 2072.78, 2080.79, 2088.82, 
2096.86, 2104.93, 2113, 2121.09, 2129.2, 2137.33, 2145.47, 2153.63, 
2161.8, 2169.99, 2178.19, 2186.41, 2194.65, 2202.9, 2211.17, 
2219.45, 2227.75, 2236.07, 2244.4, 2252.75, 2261.11, 2269.49, 
2277.88, 2286.3, 2294.72, 2303.17, 2311.62, 2320.1, 2328.59, 
2337.1, 2345.62, 2354.16, 2362.72, 2371.29, 2379.87, 2388.48, 
2397.09, 2405.73, 2414.38, 2423.05, 2431.73, 2440.43, 2449.14, 
2457.87, 2466.62, 2475.38, 2484.16, 2492.95, 2501.76, 2510.59, 
2519.43, 2528.29, 2537.17, 2546.06, 2554.96, 2563.89, 2572.82, 
2581.78, 2590.75, 2599.73, 2608.74, 2617.76, 2626.79, 2635.84, 
2644.91, 2653.99, 2663.09, 2672.2, 2681.33, 2690.48, 2699.64, 
2708.82, 2718.01, 2727.22, 2736.45, 2745.69, 2754.95, 2764.23, 
2773.52, 2782.82, 2792.15, 2801.49, 2810.84, 2820.21, 2829.6, 
2839, 2848.42, 2857.85, 2867.31, 2876.77, 2886.26, 2895.75, 2905.27, 
2914.8, 2924.35, 2933.91, 2943.49, 2953.09, 2962.7, 2972.33, 
2981.97, 2991.63, 3001.31, 3011, 3020.7, 3030.43, 3040.17, 3049.93, 
3059.7, 3069.49, 3079.29, 3089.11, 3098.95, 3108.8, 3118.67, 
3128.55, 3138.45, 3148.37, 3158.3, 3168.25, 3178.22, 3188.2, 
3198.2, 3208.21, 3218.24, 3228.29, 3238.35, 3248.43, 3258.52, 
3268.63, 3278.76, 3288.9, 3299.06, 3309.23, 3319.42, 3329.63, 
3339.85, 3350.09, 3360.35, 3370.62, 3380.9, 3391.21, 3401.53, 
3411.86, 3422.21, 3432.58, 3442.97, 3453.37, 3463.78, 3474.22, 
3484.66, 3495.13, 3505.61, 3516.11, 3526.62, 3537.15, 3547.69, 
3558.26, 3568.83, 3579.43, 3590.04, 3600.66, 3611.31, 3621.96, 
3632.64, 3643.33, 3654.04, 3664.76, 3675.5, 3686.25, 3697.03, 
3707.81, 3718.62, 3729.44, 3740.27, 3751.13, 3762, 3772.88, 3783.78, 
3794.7, 3805.63, 3816.58, 3827.55, 3838.53, 3849.53, 3860.54, 
3871.57, 3882.62, 3893.68, 3904.76, 3915.85, 3926.97, 3938.09, 
3949.24, 3960.4, 3971.57, 3982.76, 3993.97, 4005.2, 4016.44, 
4027.7, 4038.97, 4050.26, 4061.56, 4072.89, 4084.22, 4095.58, 
4106.95, 4118.33, 4129.74, 4141.16, 4152.59, 4164.04, 4175.51, 
4187, 4198.5, 4210.01, 4221.54, 4233.09, 4244.66, 4256.24, 4267.84, 
4279.45, 4291.08, 4302.73, 4314.39, 4326.07, 4337.76, 4349.47, 
4361.2, 4372.95, 4384.71, 4396.48, 4408.27, 4420.08, 4431.91, 
4443.75, 4455.61, 4467.48, 4479.37, 4491.27, 4503.2, 4515.14, 
4527.09, 4539.06, 4551.05, 4563.05, 4575.07, 4587.11, 4599.16, 
4611.23, 4623.31, 4635.42, 4647.53, 4659.67, 4671.82, 4683.98, 
4696.17, 4708.36, 4720.58, 4732.81, 4745.06, 4757.32, 4769.6, 
4781.9, 4794.21, 4806.54, 4818.89, 4831.25, 4843.63, 4856.02, 
4868.43, 4880.86, 4893.3, 4905.76, 4918.24, 4930.73, 4943.24, 
4955.76, 4968.3, 4980.86, 4993.43, 5006.02, 5018.63, 5031.25, 
5043.89, 5056.54, 5069.21, 5081.9, 5094.61, 5107.33, 5120.06, 
5132.81, 5145.58, 5158.37, 5171.17, 5183.99, 5196.82, 5209.67, 
5222.54, 5235.42, 5248.32, 5261.24, 5274.17, 5287.12, 5300.09, 
5313.07, 5326.06, 5339.08, 5352.11, 5365.16, 5378.22, 5391.3, 
5404.39, 5417.5, 5430.63, 5443.78, 5456.94, 5470.12, 5483.31, 
5496.52, 5509.75, 5522.99, 5536.25, 5549.52, 5562.81, 5576.12, 
5589.45, 5602.79, 5616.15, 5629.52, 5642.91, 5656.31, 5669.74, 
5683.18, 5696.63, 5710.1, 5723.59, 5737.1, 5750.62, 5764.15, 
5777.71, 5791.28, 5804.86, 5818.47, 5832.08, 5845.72, 5859.37, 
5873.04, 5886.72, 5900.43, 5914.14, 5927.88, 5941.63, 5955.39, 
5969.18, 5982.97, 5996.79, 6010.62, 6024.47, 6038.33, 6052.22, 
6066.11, 6080.03, 6093.96, 6107.9, 6121.87, 6135.85, 6149.84, 
6163.85, 6177.88, 6191.93, 6205.99, 6220.07, 6234.16, 6248.27, 
6262.4, 6276.54, 6290.7, 6304.88, 6319.07, 6333.28, 6347.51, 
6361.75, 6376.01, 6390.28, 6404.57, 6418.88, 6433.2, 6447.54, 
6461.9, 6476.27, 6490.66, 6505.07, 6519.49, 6533.93, 6548.39, 
6562.86, 6577.35, 6591.85, 6606.37, 6620.91, 6635.46, 6650.03, 
6664.62, 6679.22, 6693.84, 6708.48, 6723.13, 6737.8, 6752.49, 
6767.19, 6781.91, 6796.64, 6811.39, 6826.16, 6840.94, 6855.75, 
6870.56, 6885.4, 6900.25, 6915.11, 6929.99, 6944.89, 6959.81, 
6974.74, 6989.69, 7004.66, 7019.64, 7034.63, 7049.65, 7064.68, 
7079.73, 7094.79, 7109.87, 7124.97, 7140.08, 7155.21, 7170.36, 
7185.52, 7200.7, 7215.89, 7231.11, 7246.34, 7261.58, 7276.84, 
7292.12, 7307.41, 7322.73, 7338.05, 7353.4, 7368.76, 7384.13, 
7399.53, 7414.94, 7430.36, 7445.81, 7461.27, 7476.74, 7492.23, 
7507.74, 7523.27, 7538.81, 7554.37, 7569.94, 7585.53, 7601.14, 
7616.76, 7632.41, 7648.06, 7663.74, 7679.43, 7695.13, 7710.86, 
7726.6, 7742.35, 7758.13, 7773.91, 7789.72, 7805.54, 7821.38, 
7837.24, 7853.11, 7869, 7884.9, 7900.82, 7916.76, 7932.71, 7948.69, 
7964.67, 7980.68, 7996.7, 8012.73, 8028.79, 8044.86, 8060.94, 
8077.05, 8093.17, 8109.3, 8125.46, 8141.62, 8157.81, 8174.01, 
8190.23, 8206.47, 8222.72, 8238.99, 8255.27, 8271.57, 8287.89, 
8304.22, 8320.58, 8336.94, 8353.33, 8369.73, 8386.15, 8402.58, 
8419.03, 8435.5, 8451.98, 8468.48, 8485, 8501.53, 8518.08, 8534.64, 
8551.23, 8567.83, 8584.44, 8601.07, 8617.72, 8634.39, 8651.07, 
8667.77, 8684.48, 8701.22, 8717.96, 8734.73, 8751.51, 8768.31, 
8785.12, 8801.95, 8818.8, 8835.66, 8852.55, 8869.44, 8886.36, 
8903.29, 8920.23, 8937.2, 8954.18, 8971.17, 8988.19, 9005.22, 
9022.26, 9039.33, 9056.41, 9073.5, 9090.62, 9107.74, 9124.89, 
9142.05, 9159.23, 9176.43, 9193.64, 9210.87, 9228.11, 9245.38, 
9262.66, 9279.95, 9297.26, 9314.59, 9331.94, 9349.3, 9366.68, 
9384.07, 9401.48, 9418.91, 9436.35, 9453.81, 9471.29, 9488.79, 
9506.3, 9523.83, 9541.37, 9558.93, 9576.51, 9594.1, 9611.71, 
9629.34, 9646.98, 9664.64, 9682.32, 9700.01, 9717.72, 9735.45, 
9753.19, 9770.95, 9788.73, 9806.52, 9824.33, 9842.16, 9860, 9877.86, 
9895.74, 9913.63, 9931.54, 9949.47, 9967.41, 9985.37, 10003.35, 
10021.34, 10039.35, 10057.38, 10075.42, 10093.48, 10111.55, 10129.65, 
10147.76, 10165.88, 10184.02, 10202.18, 10220.36, 10238.55, 10256.76, 
10274.99, 10293.23, 10311.49, 10329.76, 10348.05, 10366.36, 10384.69, 
10403.03, 10421.39, 10439.76, 10458.16, 10476.57, 10494.99, 10513.43, 
10531.89, 10550.37, 10568.86, 10587.37, 10605.89, 10624.43, 10642.99, 
10661.57, 10680.16, 10698.77, 10717.39, 10736.04, 10754.69, 10773.37, 
10792.06, 10810.77, 10829.49, 10848.24, 10866.99, 10885.77, 10904.56, 
10923.37, 10942.2, 10961.04, 10979.9, 10998.77, 11017.66, 11036.57, 
11055.5, 11074.44, 11093.4, 11112.37, 11131.36, 11150.37, 11169.4, 
11188.44, 11207.5, 11226.57, 11245.67, 11264.77, 11283.9, 11303.04, 
11322.2, 11341.38, 11360.57, 11379.78, 11399, 11418.24, 11437.5, 
11456.78, 11476.07, 11495.38, 11514.7, 11534.05, 11553.41, 11572.78, 
11592.17, 11611.58, 11631.01, 11650.45, 11669.91, 11689.39, 11708.88, 
11728.39, 11747.91, 11767.46, 11787.02, 11806.59, 11826.18, 11845.79, 
11865.42, 11885.06, 11904.72, 11924.4, 11944.09, 11963.8, 11983.53, 
12003.27, 12023.03, 12042.81, 12062.6, 12082.41, 12102.24, 12122.08, 
12141.94, 12161.82, 12181.71, 12201.62, 12221.55, 12241.49, 12261.45, 
12281.43, 12301.42, 12321.43, 12341.46, 12361.5, 12381.57, 12401.64, 
12421.74, 12441.85, 12461.98, 12482.12, 12502.28, 12522.46, 12542.65, 
12562.87, 12583.09, 12603.34, 12623.6, 12643.88, 12664.17, 12684.49, 
12704.81, 12725.16, 12745.52, 12765.9, 12786.3, 12806.71, 12827.14, 
12847.58, 12868.04, 12888.52, 12909.02, 12929.53, 12950.06, 12970.61, 
12991.17, 13011.75, 13032.35, 13052.96, 13073.59, 13094.24, 13114.9, 
13135.58, 13156.28, 13176.99, 13197.72, 13218.47, 13239.23, 13260.01, 
13280.81, 13301.63, 13322.46, 13343.3, 13364.17, 13385.05, 13405.95, 
13426.86, 13447.79, 13468.74, 13489.71, 13510.69, 13531.69, 13552.7, 
13573.74, 13594.79, 13615.85, 13636.93, 13658.03, 13679.15, 13700.28, 
13721.43, 13742.6, 13763.78, 13784.98, 13806.2, 13827.43, 13848.68, 
13869.95, 13891.23, 13912.53, 13933.85, 13955.19, 13976.54, 13997.9, 
14019.29, 14040.69, 14062.11, 14083.54, 14104.99, 14126.46, 14147.95, 
14169.45, 14190.97, 14212.51, 14234.06, 14255.63, 14277.21, 14298.82, 
14320.44, 14342.07, 14363.73, 14385.4, 14407.08, 14428.79, 14450.51, 
14472.24, 14494, 14515.77, 14537.56, 14559.36, 14581.18, 14603.02, 
14624.87, 14646.75, 14668.63, 14690.54, 14712.46, 14734.4, 14756.36, 
14778.33, 14800.32, 14822.33, 14844.35, 14866.39, 14888.44, 14910.52, 
14932.61, 14954.72, 14976.84, 14998.98, 15021.14, 15043.31, 15065.5, 
15087.71, 15109.94, 15132.18, 15154.44, 15176.71, 15199, 15221.31, 
15243.64, 15265.98, 15288.34, 15310.72, 15333.11, 15355.52, 15377.95, 
15400.39, 15422.85, 15445.33, 15467.82, 15490.33, 15512.86, 15535.4, 
15557.96, 15580.54, 15603.14, 15625.75, 15648.38, 15671.02, 15693.69, 
15716.37, 15739.06, 15761.77, 15784.5, 15807.25, 15830.01, 15852.8, 
15875.59, 15898.41, 15921.24, 15944.08, 15966.95, 15989.83, 16012.73, 
16035.64, 16058.58, 16081.52, 16104.49, 16127.47, 16150.47, 16173.49, 
16196.52, 16219.57, 16242.64, 16265.72, 16288.82, 16311.94, 16335.07, 
16358.22, 16381.39, 16404.58, 16427.78, 16451, 16474.23, 16497.49, 
16520.75, 16544.04, 16567.34, 16590.66, 16614, 16637.35, 16660.72, 
16684.11, 16707.51, 16730.93, 16754.37, 16777.83, 16801.3, 16824.79, 
16848.29, 16871.81, 16895.35, 16918.91, 16942.48, 16966.07, 16989.68, 
17013.3, 17036.94, 17060.6, 17084.27, 17107.96, 17131.67, 17155.4, 
17179.14, 17202.9, 17226.67, 17250.46, 17274.27, 17298.1, 17321.94, 
17345.8, 17369.68, 17393.57, 17417.48, 17441.41, 17465.35, 17489.32, 
17513.29, 17537.29, 17561.3, 17585.33, 17609.37, 17633.44, 17657.52, 
17681.61, 17705.73, 17729.86, 17754, 17778.17, 17802.35, 17826.54, 
17850.76, 17874.99, 17899.24, 17923.5, 17947.79, 17972.09, 17996.4, 
18020.73, 18045.08, 18069.45, 18093.83, 18118.24, 18142.65, 18167.09, 
18191.54, 18216.01, 18240.49, 18264.99, 18289.51, 18314.05, 18338.6, 
18363.17, 18387.76, 18412.36, 18436.98, 18461.62, 18486.27, 18510.94, 
18535.63, 18560.34, 18585.06, 18609.8, 18634.55, 18659.33, 18684.12, 
18708.92, 18733.75, 18758.59, 18783.44, 18808.32, 18833.21, 18858.12, 
18883.04, 18907.98, 18932.94, 18957.92, 18982.91, 19007.92, 19032.95, 
19057.99, 19083.05, 19108.13, 19133.22, 19158.33, 19183.46, 19208.61, 
19233.77, 19258.95, 19284.15, 19309.36, 19334.59, 19359.83, 19385.1, 
19410.38, 19435.68, 19460.99, 19486.32, 19511.67, 19537.04, 19562.42, 
19587.82, 19613.23, 19638.67, 19664.12, 19689.58, 19715.07, 19740.57, 
19766.09, 19791.62, 19817.17, 19842.74, 19868.33, 19893.93, 19919.55, 
19945.19, 19970.84, 19996.51, 20022.2, 20047.9, 20073.62, 20099.36, 
20125.12, 20150.89, 20176.68, 20202.49, 20228.31, 20254.15, 20280.01, 
20305.88, 20331.77, 20357.68, 20383.6, 20409.55, 20435.51, 20461.48, 
20487.47, 20513.48, 20539.51, 20565.55, 20591.61, 20617.69, 20643.79, 
20669.9, 20696.03, 20722.17, 20748.34, 20774.51, 20800.71, 20826.92, 
20853.15, 20879.4, 20905.67, 20931.95, 20958.25, 20984.56, 21010.89, 
21037.24, 21063.61, 21089.99, 21116.39, 21142.81, 21169.24, 21195.7, 
21222.16, 21248.65, 21275.15, 21301.67, 21328.21, 21354.76, 21381.33, 
21407.92, 21434.52, 21461.14, 21487.78, 21514.43, 21541.11, 21567.8, 
21594.5, 21621.22, 21647.96, 21674.72, 21701.5, 21728.29, 21755.09, 
21781.92, 21808.76, 21835.62, 21862.5, 21889.39, 21916.3, 21943.23, 
21970.17, 21997.13, 22024.11, 22051.1, 22078.12, 22105.14, 22132.19, 
22159.25, 22186.33, 22213.43, 22240.54, 22267.68, 22294.82, 22321.99, 
22349.17, 22376.37)), row.names = c(NA, -1651L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi there. You have not supplied your data. You have linked to a _picture_ of your data. No-one will be able to reproduce your set-up unless they manually transcribe this picture into text, and it's very unlikely anyone will do this. Please help us to help you by including a sample of your data by typing `dput(a)` into your console, then pasting the resulting output into your question. You can edit your question using the gray "edit" link just below it.Thanks

Comment: Thank you!!! I will do this next time. I added the information from dput(a)

Comment: edited your reproducible data and fixed 3 issues.

Comment: @user14368610: take a look at these examples https://stackoverflow.com/a/48915171/786542 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/54135578/786542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach. I have used `a` with simulated data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
#Data
a <- data.frame(Gageheight=seq(1.0,by=0.1,length.out = 1651),
                Discharge=seq(9.92,by=0.56,length.out = 1651))
#Function
lm_eqn <- function(df){
  m <- lm(Gageheight ~ Discharge, df);
  eq <- substitute(italic(Gageheight) == a + b %.% italic(Discharge)*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2, 
                   list(a = format(unname(coef(m)[1]), digits = 2),
                        b = format(unname(coef(m)[2]), digits = 2),
                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3)))
  as.character(as.expression(eq));
}
#Code
ggplot(a, aes(x = Discharge, y = Gageheight) ) + geom_point(size=0.5) +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black", formula = y ~ x)+
  geom_text(x = 2, y = 100, label = lm_eqn(a), parse = TRUE)+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

And using the real `a` you shared and that was fixed by @sindri_baldur (Many thanks!):

```
#Code 2
ggplot(a, aes(x = Discharge, y = Gageheight) ) + geom_point(size=0.5) +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black", formula = y ~ x)+
  geom_text(x = 2, y = 10, label = lm_eqn(a), parse = TRUE)+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Okay, I want to make sure people get credit when credit is due. I will pass this info on also.